# PHP form issue , reading from a form issue

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a problem with my php code.so This is my form written in a php page:

```
echo "<form action='strg_cont.php' method=\"post\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"name\" value=".$info['email'] .">
    <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Delete\">
    </form> "
```

And this is my read strg_cont.php code:

```
<?php session_start();

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
$myEmail = $_POST['email'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username="root";
$conn = @mysql_connect($servername,$username) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("db_onco",$conn);
$emailPentruSterge = mysql_real_escape_string($contact_name);
$verifica_exista_email = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacte WHERE email = '$emailPentruSterge'");
..............

}
?>
```

Why in my `str_cont.ph`p code `$_POST['email'`] is blank and if block is not "executed"? I don't read correct information or what problem i have?
Thanks.

Comment: This style of php is very old: look into templates and [PDO](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059).

Comment: yeah I forgot to mention the boilerplate don't use `mysql` it's deprecated, parametrized queries are safer and all that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"name\" value=".$info['email'] .">
```

Means that `$_POST['name']` is sent, not `$_POST['email']`.

change it to

```
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"email\" value=".$info['email'] .">
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at code,
this is your form

```
echo "<form action='strg_cont.php' method=\"post\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"email\" value=".$info['email'] .">
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Delete\">
</form> ";
```

and this is for processing code

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
$myEmail = $_POST['email'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username="root";
$conn = @mysql_connect($servername,$username) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("db_onco",$conn);
$emailPentruSterge = mysql_real_escape_string($myEmail);
$verifica_exista_email = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacte WHERE email = '$emailPentruSterge'");

}
```

Cheers;